# How can my Woocommerce (Wordpress) user login in two separate sites with same account?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to configuire Wordpress, so that two sites share the user database?

I have ( or plan) two separate Woocommerce Shops and want that my customers can login with the same username and password on both sites. Is it possible? What is the best way?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, when you set up WordPress it asks for your database. You normally answer with "localhost". Read up on what you need to answer instead.

Comment: thx, but I don't want to share the whole database, not the articles, not the posts, not the shop items, but only the user table.